# nsfetchresultcontroller returns rows after delete

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I'm using parent/child context for core data. objects are added in background thread and context. that works fine. the objects are also deleted in the background context and saved on child/parent. i can see that in core data debug that objects are deleted and commit successfully. after that i'm telling the nsfetchresultcontroller(setting to nil and reinitializing and deleting cache) to fetch objects. the objects are still there, eventhough the objects were deleted.

```
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZTLOG(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZFXY, ZFXYZ) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
```

delete

```
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: sql: DELETE FROM ZTLOG WHERE Z_PK = ? AND Z_OPT = ?
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
```

nsfetchresultcontroller

```
CoreData: annotation: fetch using NSSQLiteStatement <0x68a2760> on entity 'TLog' with sql text 'SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZXY, t0.ZXYZ WHERE  t0.Z_PK = ? ' returned 0 rows
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0080s for 0 rows.
CoreData: annotation: fault fulfilled from database for : 0x687ab40 <x-coredata://BCA24D29-F9D3-4068-8122-E7A43C116D8A/TLog/p2>
```

so the table view has still the object even though i set fetchcontroller & delegate to nil and did re init. but still the fetchresult controller fetchedobjects has the object deleted.
the last log line looks suspicious. i deleted all objects. why it fulfills the fault?

anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once again it was threading problem. core data objects are not thread safe!